# Can't access site hosted on local VM from Edge

Tags: vmware, microsoft-edge, loopback

I have a site running on a local VM (VMWare Workstation, CentOS7).
I can access it just fine from Chrome, Firefox and IE11, but Edge simply doesn't work.

I've tried running `CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`

, tried enabling the "Allow localhost loopback" flag in "about:flags" and tried the solutions suggested [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0face535-3c7a-4658-be34-6c376322ca34/microsoft-edge-cant-open-local-domains?forum=win10itpronetworking) and [here](https://appuals.com/edge-responds-we-cant-reach-this-page/) but nothing seems to work. I keep getting "Hmmm...can’t reach this page" with error code `INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your site's URL in each browser?

Comment: It's 192.168.10.x

Comment: @OmriHeffer Did you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem here with a VM internal IP address that can be accessed by IE11, Chrome and Firefox, but not Edge.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. My workaround (which was sufficient for me to meet the objective of accessing a website, hosted within a VMWare Linux VM, from Edge) was to use port forwarding, e.g. (from an administrator command prompt) :
 `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8001 connectaddress=192.168.x.y connectport=80`

I can now access the website from within Edge using localhost:8001

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar problem.

The problem here was that IE had localhost set in Local Intranet, and "Enable Protected Mode" checked for Local Intranet,

The result was that a local browser "Run as Administrator" would browse to the site, but when run normally, would not.

The solution in this case was to disable Protected Mode for Local Intranet, or to remove localhost from the local intranet and add it to Trusted Sites.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But after I changed my VMWare network Connection Type to bridged networking, it worked well. I can use MicrosoftEdge to open the web site running on a local VM (VMWare Workstation, CentOS7), but it was not worked on network address translation (NAT) Type.